# 'Intermediate variable' while rendering in Angular?

Tags: angular

Note: I can't find the correct search terms to find for sure if this is a duplicate question or if Angular offers the concept I'm looking for. Therefore, apologies it this sounds obvious or unclear.

Context: I have a React background. Just like React, an Angular component receives some input data from its parent and updates its internal state when required; then it re-renders what needs to be re-rendered if required.

**Sometimes, you want to pass down some of the data** that you got either from the component's input or internal state, down to an inner component.

In **Angular** it would be like this :

```
/* my-parent-component.ts */
export class MyParentComponent ... {
  ...
  @Input() someArray: string[];
  ...
}


====================================


/* my-parent-component.html */
<div>
   ...
   <my-child-component
       [passedDownField]="someArray"
   ></my-child-component>
</div>
```

Sometimes, you want to **transform** that data before passing it down. For example, if I don't want to pass down the array but instead some computation on the array:

```
/* my-parent-component.html */
<div>
   ...
   <my-child-component
       [transformedField]="someArray.length > 0"
   />
</div>
```

Now imagine that the transformation is complex, plus I want to re-use it in several places. **I would like to put it in some sort of intermediate variable.**

In **functional React** it would be as simple as :

```
const MyParentComponent = (someArray: string[]) => {
   ...
   // Logic in only one place, with an intermediate variable.
   const myTransformedVar: bool = someArray.length > 0;
   ...
  return (<>
    <MyChildComponent¨
        id="1"
        transformedField={myTransformedVar}
    />
     <MyChildComponent
         id="2"
        transformedField={myTransformedVar}
    /> 
    <MyChildComponent
        id="3"
        transformedField={myTransformedVar}
    /></>
  );

}
```

**Notice how this so-called "intermediate variable" is not part of the state.** It's not listening to anything and has a tiny scope and lifetime. It just pops when a re-render takes place, and get deleted immediately after.

**Question : is there some equivalent to this in Angular?**

I have found two potential equivalents :

1. Add a member field named "myTransformedVar" in MyParentComponent. Then add a getter and a **setter** on "someArray", and in the setter update myTransformedVar.
2. Add a member field named "myTransformedVar" in MyParentComponent.  Then add **ngOnChange** to MyParentComponent, and inside of it update myTransformedVar when someArray has changed.

Both seem unnecessarily clunky; worse, they make the programmer look in a different place to see the logic than just following along the rendering flow. Any ideas?

Comment: You mean like `PIPE`?

Comment: Is that what pipe is for? Isn't there a huge asynchronous aspect to pipes?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/pipes . Check if that fits your needs in the first place (as I have no clue what your requirement is)

Comment: @Antoniossss I think you understood pretty well what I'm after, and pipes seem to do the trick, but that syntax is still extremely heavy (separate file, imports, etc.).  Can you think of some compact syntax for pipes? I.e. **some sort "inline" pipe** ?

Comment: You have two possibilities (forget ngOnChange): pipes and transform (since v16.1.0). If you want to reuse it, then you should extract the logic in a separate file anyway. With pipe you transform the input value on the parent component, with transform you do it in the child component itself. Looking at the react example I think, transform is exactly the same in Angular.

Comment: If you only need to do it within a single component you can just have a method on that class to transform your data `[transformedField]="mySpecialFunc(myData)"` - otherwise, yes I agree a pipe is the better option. Once you set it up it's available anywhere to use.

Comment: @derstauner what is the difference between "transform" and what Chris Barr suggested (a simple function) ? EDIT: I've rad on it, it's clear now.

Comment: With transform you define also a simple function (f. e. in a service). It is intended exactly for input transformation, avoiding the setter pattern. Search after it.

Comment: @derstauner your answer is the closest one to my need. You should write it and I'l accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a locally-defined function  :

```
/* my-parent-component.ts */
export class MyParentComponent ... {
  ...
  @Input() someArray: string[];
  ...
  public hasItems(array: string[]):boolean {
      return array.length > 0;
  }
}

===============

/* my-parent-component.html */
<div>
   ...
   <my-child-component
       [transformedField]="hasItems(someArray)"
   />
</div>
```

**OBJECTIONS TO THIS MODEL :**

**1. "It is recalculated every time"**

Yes, that's the point. The original complex expression `someArray.length > 0` was already recalculated every time anyways. Except now the logic is in only one place, and the html is not cluttered with it.

**2. Angular cannot know if the result of the function has changed**

Correct. Same as any intermediate variable used in React, which is a very common thing to do.

It's a choice: If someArray changes, then the intermediate variable changes too. And it should indeed be a deterministic function to avoid side effects.

It's the same tradeoff in React known as *"should I use a local variable OR should I memoize the value/do a useEffect?".*

I was specifically asking about the case when you DON'T want to memoize/useEffect, i.e. don't need to change the component's state. A local variable will do just fine. And therefore, the improvised Angular equivalent of using a function (`hasItems`) will do just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Angular v16.1.0 you can simply transform your input values without having a setter method in the component code.

For this you define a function, f. e. like this:

```
function toNumber(value: string | number) {
  return isNumber(value) ? value : parseInt(value);
}
```

Of course you can write this function f. e. in a service, if you want to reuse it.

Then in the child component you can use it like this:

```
@Input({ transform: toNumber }) width: number;
```

For further reading see [this](https://netbasal.com/say-goodbye-to-setters-and-getters-angulars-transform-option-for-input-values-88fd9442dcad).

EDIT:

Why is it a bad idea to use functions in templates? Because Angular cannot predict whether the return value of the given function has changed, it needs to execute the function every time change detection runs. And this can be heavy.

Exactly this is why I suggest the new feature `transform`, or alternativly a pure pipe. For both you implement your logic once and use it where you want.

Comment: In my case I was more after the `[transformedField]="mySpecialFunc(myData)"` solution, but I will still mark this as the accepted answer as it can work too.

Comment: I have added my own answer